# does not contain a definiton for where for linq

Tags: mysql, .net, linq, contains

I want to query from Users table with linq query.   I am getting an error on this line on "Users.Where";
var KisiList = Users.Where(w => w.Userstatus == 1 && w.Isactive == 1).ToList();
Users does not contain a definiton for where. what should I add here?

```
public List<Users> GetBagliOlduguKisiList()
{

     var KisiList = Users.Where(w => w.Userstatus == 1 && w.Isactive == 1).ToList();
    List< Users> users= new List< Users>();
    
    foreach (var item in KisiList )
    {
        Users par= new Users();
        par. ID= item. ID;
        par. Name= item. Name;
        users.Add(par);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: Where is  your DBContext?

Comment: where should i use DBContext?

Comment: Add on top of your file: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have missed `using System.Linq;`. Also if you are using LINQ, try to do that effectively and retrieve only needed fields.

```cs
public List<Users> GetBagliOlduguKisiList()
{
    var users = Users
       .Where(w => w.Userstatus == 1 && w.Isactive == 1)
       .Select(u => new Users
       { 
          ID = u.ID,
          Name = u.Name
       })
       .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

Comment: I added using using System.Linq, but I think i missed  things like Queryable or dbcontext

Comment: So, what is the Users?

Comment: Users is the class name I created.

Comment: So, that it is your probem. `Where` can be applied only to IQueryable or IEnumerable.